# How to add an event handler for dynamically created QML elements?

Tags: qt, qml

I dynamically added some qml components to my gui according to [this blog post](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.kr/2011/04/creating-qml-element-dynamically-on.html). How can I add event handlers for those newly created components?

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What kind of event handling are you talking about?

Comment: I've created some buttons dynamically like as shown in the above link. Now i want to associate some functionality for Button Click events of those dynamically created buttons.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Do not add [Solved] to the title. To indicate a "solved" question, simply upvote and accept an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'll explain with an example. 
1)Create a custom button component as follows

```
//Button.qml ... This component's objects will be dynamically
// created
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 50
    color:"blue"
    //Since the buttons are created on the fly,
    //we need to identify the button on which the user
    // has clicked. The id must be unique
    property string buttonId;
    signal clicked(string buttonId);

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:parent.clicked(parent.buttonId)
    }
}
```

This is a simple button which emits clicked signal on clicking on it..
Now lets create some buttons on the fly.

```
//Main.qml ... creates some buttons on the fly
import QtQuick 2.1
Rectangle{
    id:root
    width:500
    height:500

    function buttonClicked(buttonId)
    {
        console.debug(buttonId);
    }

    function createSomeButtons()
    {
        //Function creates 4 buttons
        var component = Qt.createComponent("Button.qml");
        for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            var buttonY = i*55; //Button height : 50 + 5 unit margin
            var button = component.createObject(root,{"x":0,"y":buttonY,"buttonId":i+1});

            //Connect the clicked signal of the newly created button
            //to the event handler buttonClicked.
            button.clicked.connect(buttonClicked)
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        createSomeButtons();
    }
}
```

Here when the Main.qml component creation has been completed, buttons are created.
4 buttons are created and after creation of each button, the javascript function   buttonClicked is connected as event handler to the '*Button.qml*''s *clicked* signal. Whenever the user clicks on the button, *buttonClicked* function will be called with *buttonId* as argument. You can do whatever you want in the event handler from here on.

Comment: I don't understand how `buttonId` argument is passed to the signal

Comment: Link to the relevant part of the Qt reference manual: [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html).

Comment: Not good idea to call a signal `clicked`, this overrides the default `clicked()` signal from eg `Button`...