# QML submenu / action creation

Tags: qml, submenu

I'm  trying to create a contextMenu for a rightClick action. The Menu has two SubMenus, "print in ..." and other subMenu. When I hoverover "print in..." it display the submenu, but to create this submenu it has to consult how many printers are availables in that moment. I can create the complete subMenu listing all the printers using the "MENU.addItem()" but I can't set the "onTriggered" handler to add an action to these Items. How can I fix it

Comment: What about exploiting `connect` and follow the approach described, for example, in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603170/how-to-add-an-event-handler-for-dynamically-created-qml-elements)?

Comment: I prove this for another application and it works perfectly, the signals and the connections, just end with this part and I'll prove it creating all the context menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @BaCaRoZzo commented the connect and the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603170/how-to-add-an-event-handler-for-dynamically-created-qml-elements) works very well for this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
Menu {
    id: contextMenu
    Menu {
        title: "print in..."
        id: submenu1
        onPopupVisibleChanged: {
            submenu1.clear();
            for(var i =0;i < 10;i ++) {
                submenu1.addItem("item" + i);
            }
        }
    }
    Menu {
        title: "another submenu"
        MenuItem {
            text: "submenu_item1"
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "submenu_item2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already prove that, using a For Loop but in that way I can't add the onTriggered handler